# How do you say “my friend is throwing a party, do you wanna come?” in german

Tags: translation

What is the “umgangsprachliche” way to say:

> Hey, my friend is throwing a party on saturday. Do you want to come?

It’s a more casual thing, so I didn’t want to say

> Ein Freund von mir veranstaltet eine Feier.

because it sounded too “formal”.

Comment: Just to be sure: Are you certain extending the invitation that you received to other people is expected by the inviting person? Just saying because parties where guests bring other people, so that people who are total strangers to the host (and not a significant other of one of the directly invited guests) end up attending are something that I've seen almostcexclusively in American movies. (This might be a cultural difference, or it might also be due to my personal total lack of experience with anything party-like - I'm genuinely not sure ;) )

Comment: Is there any problem with the edits?

Comment: yes, I tried to edit the question and some random characters appeared (my laptop is going crazy these days). I tried to edit it again and it wouldn't let me, although now it appears as the original question is back up!!

Comment: There are rollback links to go back to earlier edits, I used that. I was wondering why you would vandalise your own question ;)  Good luck with your laptop then.

Comment: And my best friend is the one throwing the party and I -obviously- asked before hand if I could invite the other friend :) thanks for the explanation anyway! Haha and gor all these answers also, they have been very helpful!

Comment: _Ein Freund macht am Samstag 'ne Party. Magst du (mit)kommen?_

Answer (score 23):

> Mein Freund schmeißt eine Party. Willst du vorbei kommen?

You can also say *Kumpel* instead of friend. It means something like buddy.

Comment: So it's exactly the same in German and English. As "schmeißen" translates to "to throw"

Comment: @miep yeah but it is not the formal way, you would rather say in formal "er macht eine Party" for example.

Comment: @miep: it would not entirely surprise me if the use of *schmeißen* came from the English original.

Comment: @Rudy yeah, that could be the case. Another famous example is "Sinn machen" from "make Sense" even though the correct German form would be "Sinn ergeben". But nowadays only few people still say "Sinn ergeben".

Comment: IS *schmeißen* only for parties, or can you use it with *Fußball* and other such things? (To throw something away, etc.)

Comment: *Schmeiß weg! – Throw away!*

Comment: For me (native speaker) *eine Party schmeißen* sounds rather old-fashioned. May have been en vogue in the 1950s... I cannot imagine friends of mine (age range 30-40) to use that but perhaps ironically. Of course, this may be different in other geographical regions or social niches.

Comment: @Rudy But there is also "eine Runde/ein Bier schmeißen" which seems to be a quite old expression.

Comment: @BruceWayne: "Einen Fußball schmeißen" is possible, but you just throw the ball. If you mean "play/start/organize a game of soccer", then "schmeißen" is wrong.

Comment: "Ein Bier Schmeißen" is an act of agression and probably quite a waste. "Eine Runde schmeißen" makes sense (to get in a round).

Comment: Must be "vorbeikommen" without a space.

Comment: @miep: English may have promoted "Sinn machen" - but the expression is not completely new or foreign to German. It had already been used by Goethe, Lessing or Luther ([see](http://rapunzelturm.blogspot.com/2015/09/kann-etwas-sinn-machen-und-der-spa-am.html)).

Answer (score 15):

The typical "umgangssprachliche" way would be to say

> Ein Freund / eine Freundin von mir feiert am Samstag. Willst du mitkommen?

While using the literal translation *Mein Freund* / *Meine Freundin* is not wrong, depending on who says it it can be misunderstood as *My boyfriend* / *My girlfriend*.

If you want to stress that it is a really good friend of yours use *Ein guter Freund* / *eine gute Freundin*, or in your case *Mein bester Freund* / *Meine beste Freundin*

*feiert* is the literal translation of *celebrates* and can umgangssprachlich be used as is. But if you prefer to leave no questions about the reason for the celebration you can say *feiert am Samstag eine Party*, saying that it's partying just because, casually as you described.

As for the verb asking the person to come use *mitkommen* if you will show up together (like *come with me*) or *vorbeikommen* if you will show up individually (like *drop by*). In a subtler tone *mitkommen* (in comparison to *vorbeikommen*) implies a more connected relationship to the person you are asking.

Answer (score 10):

I am rather unhappy with most of what has been suggested so far.<sup>1</sup> Especially *mein Freund schmeißt eine Party* sounds pretty old-fashioned to me. (See my comment underneath that answer.)

So what could be said - in casual oral communication - in the world of German where I live?

> Der Fritz macht am Samstag eine Party. Kommst du mit?
>
> Beim Fritz gibts am Samstag Party. Gehst du hin?
>
> Die Lisa feiert am Samstag. Wir sind eingeladen.
>
> Die Gudrun macht am Freitag 'nen Cowboy- und Indianerabend. Soll'n wir hingeh'n?
>
> Bei unser'n Nachbarn ist am Wochenende Party. Lass uns lieber wegfahr'n.
>
> Bei den Nachbarn ist am Wochenende wieder Halligalli. Mir reicht's allmählich mit den Studentenfeiern immer.
>
> Der Eugen feiert seinen Vierzigsten. Da müssen wir hin.
>
> Bei Müllers wird gefeiert am Samstag. Ich muss noch Blumen kaufen.

Most of the other things mentioned in other answers sound for me either bookish or stiff. Perhaps to be met in a novel by Erich Kästner but not in today's everyday communication.

---

<sup>1)</sup> With the exception of Benedikt's *xyz feiert*, of course.

Comment: "mein Freund schmeißt eine Party sounds pretty old-fashioned to me." - Na toll, jetzt fühle ich mich gerade so richtig alt. Vielen Dank!

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Es kann natürlich auch sein, dass das der tolale, hippe Modeausdruck unter 22jährigen ist, und ich (in den ohne weiteres zwei 22jährige hineinpassen), weiß das einfach nicht...

Comment: Also, obwohl ich nicht gerade der schlankste bin, würden zwei 22 nur dann in mich hineinpassen, wenn beide heftige Anorexie hätten...

Comment: P.S. bevor Du Dich genötigt siehst, eine umfassende Klarstellung zu schreiben: das eben war natürlich ein absichtliches Mis(t)verständnis ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You look for

> eine Feier geben *(casual party)*
>
> ein Gelage veranstalten *(eat-and-drink until the bellybutton pops out)*
>
> ein Saufgelage veranstalten *(beer, beer, beer, beer, beer, and a bit of booze)*
>
> eine Party schmeißen *(expect anything up to booze a-go-go)*

Comment: "Eine Feier geben" is pretty formal and could well be the 25th wedding anniversary of my parents, for which you'd get your good suit out of the back of your armoire.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use

> "Mein Freund gibt eine Party. Willst Du vorbeikommen?"

which is less "umgangssprachlich" than

> "Mein Freund schmeißt eine Party. Willst du vorbeikommen?"

while not being formal.

Comment: Please note that "schmeisst" is correct in Suiss German only, standard German requires the word to be written "schmeißt". Also, "Du" must be lowercase.

Comment: @rexkogitans why does the "Du" have to be lowercase? I might be wrong but I think it can be capital too.

Comment: @Skalli when writing a letter, you are allowed to capitalise "du", otherwise not.

Answer (score 4):

1. Part: "Bei (ei)nem Kumpel is(t) Samstag Party"
2. Part A) Willste (=willst du) mit? 
   or
3. Part B) Bock?

Comment: This seems like the only answer but a real German 

Comment: "Yoo, Samstag pardy! Kommsch?"  is how i would form it ^^

Comment: If you address it to teens from Hessen that would probably more suitable ;)